# permission denied to set parameter "lc_monetary" to "C"

Tags: npgsql

i'm trying to open a connection and i'm getting the following error:

> permission denied to set parameter "lc_monetary" to "C"

what should I do?

Comment: Did this happen while trying to connect to Amazon Redshift?

Comment: Yes. I used the driver from:
http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/

eventually, I connected using ODBC and it worked from there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had the same problem trying to connect to an [Amazon Redshift](http://aws.amazon.com/redshift/) cluster while using the recommended library, [Npgsql](https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql).

What worked for me was the removal/commenting of the following line at the file [NpgsqlStartupPacket.cs @ 63](https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql/blob/master/Npgsql/Npgsql/NpgsqlStartupPacket.cs#L63):

```
parameters.Add("lc_monetary", "C");
```

The same lc_monetary setting appears in another file which has a description of it's use: [NpgsqlConnector.cs @ 953](https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql/blob/master/Npgsql/Npgsql/NpgsqlConnector.cs#L953).

However, this **should not** be taken as a solution but a workaround since I am yet to determine the impact of this change. But it looks like Redshift doesn't support this feature.

Comment: The impact of this change will be on money datatype support. If your postgresql doesn't handle decimal values with a point, like 123.45 and/or doesn't return negative money values as -123.45 you will have problems. If your current locale is US, you won't have any problem. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @FranciscoJunior it's nice to have feedback from the lib developer. I am using Amazon Redshift and since they only implement a subset of the Postgres spec I'm assuming EN-US is the default locale and, therefore, I shouldn't have any problem with this setting. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, @MateusBR. I'm glad to hear you are using Npgsql in this environment (although there is this problem we are working to fix). There is an issue open about that which you may want to check out for information about the progress of this problem: https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql/issues/163 Thanks for feedback.